# SELinux Prevents Java from Running

Tags: java, debian, selinux

I recently installed Sun Java on a system with a fairly basic SELinux install on it.

I'm running Debian Etch and installed the Sun Java package from the non-free package repository.

Here are the error notices that appear in the syslog when I run `java -version`.

`Feb  9 14:02:40 dev kernel: audit(1265742160.570:4107): avc:  denied  { execmem } for  pid=9882 comm="java" scontext=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0 tcontext=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0 tclass=process

Feb  9 14:02:40 dev kernel: audit(1265742160.578:4108): avc:  denied  { execmem } for  pid=9882 comm="java" scontext=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0 tcontext=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0 tclass=process`

I've googled around and it seems that I need to create an SELinux policy that permits Java to perform operations that violate the `execmem` constraints. Is this a correct assumption? If so, how should I get started?

Updates:

I looked for and found a targeted policy aimed at handling Java. I installed it using the following command:

`$ sudo semodule -i /usr/share/selinux/refpolicy-targeted/java.pp`

This did not help, however. I continue to see identical audit messages in the syslog.

Comment: @jkndrkn: one of the major security flaw of most Linux distro is that you need to be root to install .deb or .rpm packages.  It seems you're concerned about security.  I sure am.  That's why I never ever install Java as root.  I take the .tar.gz and install it as a user, from a user account.  On Windows you cannot install Java without having the admin password.  On Linux you can.  Never ever install Java as root if you're concerned by security issues. (probably won't help your SELinux issue but thought I'd mention it, most people are unaware that you can install Java in a normal user account)

Comment: @Wizardofodds Actually you can install rpm's and .deb's in a chroot.  I don't think you can call it a secuirty flaw of Linux when the alternative is Windows where absolutely everything runs as a super user and you can't install anything as a normal user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide: http://etbe.coker.com.au/2006/12/08/se-linux-on-debian-in-5-minutes/ and dgrift on #selinux clued me in on the correct solution.

```
# semodule -i /usr/share/selinux/refpolicy-targeted/java.pp
# restorecon -r -v /usr
```

There is a targeted policy available for Java that has to be applied using `semodule`. Once the policy is applied, `restorecon` has to be used to apply the policy to the Java binaries.